# Rewrite existing spring application in Python

Tags: python, spring

I am new to Python. We have an existing API developed using java spring framework, which basically consume SOAP web services and return response.How can this be rewritten in Python? Is converting line by line from Java to Python good approach. What Python framework is suitable in this case. Please can someone give brief overview/steps for this.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and it looks like [zeep](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/) or [suds](https://github.com/suds-community/suds) are your best choices for SOAP.

But since you change the stack I suggest considering REST also. Most popular variants would be [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/), [Django Ninja](https://django-ninja.dev/) or [Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

> Is converting line by line from Java to Python good approach?

It depends. The syntax is very different. You should choose the framework that suits your case best and rebuild all the logic.

Hope this helps.